# Swift set constraints from code - View under view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, constraints

I'm using this extension method to set my view anchors:

```
@discardableResult
open func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()
    
    if let top = top {
        anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
    }
    
    if let leading = leading {
        anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
    }
    
    if let bottom = bottom {
        anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
    }
    
    if let trailing = trailing {
        anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
    }
    
    if size.width != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
    }
    
    if size.height != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
    }
    
    [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach{ $0?.isActive = true }
    
    return anchoredConstraints
}
```

In my app, I have two labels and I want to set under both of them a UITextField with this code:

```
widTextLabel.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0))
widTextLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: -70).isActive = true

heiTextLabel.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil)
heiTextLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true

widTextField.anchor(top: widTextLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
widTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widTextLabel.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

heiTextField.anchor(top: heiTextLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
heiTextLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heiTextLabel.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

And I get this error in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x6000015d9b40 "UITextField:0x7fdf8501a800.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x6000015d9b00 "UILabel:0x7fdf84e13cd0'test'.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Comment: The exception is right. Where is UILabel test placed? Suggestion to go in IB again and clean the constrains of that label.

Comment: `they have no common ancestor` that is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to my low rep. Have you added all of these views as subviews to your main view?

I was using the exact same extension and had the same problem yesterday. I solved it by going through my code and adding all the views before setting any constraints. Obvious mistake, but easy to make in a rush.